# How to get (write) token in the ResetPasswordToken Session?

Tags: meteor

I wrote a Reset Password function :

- the user collection (`services>password>reset`) is well setted
- the mail is sended well
- the link in the mail route me to the right url (right token in it)
- on this page, the session `resetPasswordToken` is set **but with
  `undefined` value**: I can't automatically write the token here - if I write manually the token here, everything's fine, the password is well reseted, the session `resetPasswordToken` is after that well setted to `null`.

So how to write the token in the session ? Thanks.

Below my code.

**

**The link client to get a new password**

```
<p class="info"><a href="#" class="send-reset-password-link">Resend verification link</a></p>
```

**The event on click (client)**

```
Template.UserProfile.events({
  //resend verification link function
  'click .send-reset-password-link' ( event, template ) {
      Meteor.call( 'sendResetPasswordLink', ( error, response ) => {
    if ( error ) {
      Bert.alert({
        title: 'Error',
        message: error.reason,
        type: 'danger'
      });
    } else {
          let email = Meteor.user().emails[ 0 ].address;
          Bert.alert({
            title: 'Reset Password Link sended',
            message: 'Please check your mails.',
            type: 'info'
          });
        }
      });
  }
});
```

**The method to send the link (server)**

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendResetPasswordLink() {
    let userId = Meteor.userId();
    if ( userId ) {
      return Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail( userId );
    }
  }
});
```

**The resetpassword email template (server)**

```
//resetPassword Template
Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = "Me";
Accounts.emailTemplates.from     = "Me <my@mail.com>";
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.subject = function (user) {
  return "Reset Your Password";
};
// html template
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.html = function (user, url) {
  SSR.compileTemplate( 'htmlEmail', Assets.getText( 'emailverification.html' ) );
  let emailAddress   = user.emails[0].address,
      userAvatar = user.profile.avatar,
      urlWithoutHash = url.replace( '#/', '' );
  var emailData = {
    urlWithoutHash: `${urlWithoutHash}`,
    userAvatar: `${userAvatar}`,
  };
  return SSR.render( 'htmlEmail', emailData );
};
```

**The route**

```
FlowRouter.route( '/reset-password/:token', {
  name: 'reset-password',
  action( params ) {
    BlazeLayout.render('ResetPassword', {content: 'body'});
    Accounts.resetPassword( params.token, ( error ) =>{
      if ( error ) {
        Bert.alert({
          title: 'Error',
          message: error.reason,
          type: 'danger'
        });
      } else {
        FlowRouter.go( '/' );
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**And finally, the resetpassword template**

```
//resetpassword.html
<template name="ResetPassword">


<form action="/reset-password"  class="reset-password" id="resetPasswordForm" method="post">
    <input id="resetPasswordPassword" name="password" placeholder="New Password" type="password" >
   <!--  <input id="resetPasswordPasswordConfirm" name="password-confirm" placeholder="Confirm" type="password" > -->
    <button class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>
<!-- end #reset-password-form -->

</template>

//resetpassword.js

if (Accounts.resetPassword) {
      Session.set('resetPasswordToken', Accounts.resetPassword);
    }


Template.ResetPassword.helpers({
 resetPassword: function(){
  return Session.get('resetPasswordToken');
 }
});

Template.ResetPassword.events({
 "submit .reset-password": (event) => {
    // Prevent default browser form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    //let token;
    // Get value from form element
    const target = event.target;
    const password = event.target.password.value;

    // If the password is valid, we can reset it.
    if (password) {
      //Accounts.resetPassword(token, password, (error) => {
      Accounts.resetPassword(Session.get('resetPasswordToken'), password, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          Bert.alert({
            title: 'Error',
            message: error.reason,
            type: 'danger'
          });
        } else {
          Bert.alert({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Account successfully created.',
                type: 'success'
              });
          Session.set('resetPasswordToken', null);
          //Router.go('postsList');
        }
      });
    } else {
        Bert.alert({
            title: 'Error',
            message: 'The password cannot be empty.',
            type: 'danger'
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Whay are you calling `Accounts.resetPassword()` in your router?

Comment: @MasterAM Sorry, I don't understand. Could you be more specific ? Thanks.

Comment: In your router code, after `BlazeLayout.render...` you are calling `Accounts.resetPassword( params.token...`. Why are you doing this? You need to ask the user for a new password. I don't think that the session variable is set. You can try to set it in the router.

Comment: @MasterAM I think you're right, I picked this on a very old tutorial... How do I proceed to set the session variable?

Comment: `Session.set('resetPasswordToken', params.token)` or something similar.

Comment: @MasterAM in the `route.js`, instead of `Accounts.resetPassword`?

Comment: Yes. Don't be afraid to change stuff. If you are not using source control, this is the time to start.

Comment: @MasterAM Right, works very fine, thanks you! And sorry for my last question, I was walking on the street and make you waste your time... Won't happen again.